# How to earn reputation here?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I want to upvote meaningful comments and downvote useless comments. And the most important thing is to comment on threads that I like participating in. so yeah, How to earn a reputation?

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking in terms of "comments" and "threads" you're missing the point of this site, which will make it harder to figure out how to earn reputation. This isn't a discussion site; it's a question and answer site. Asking good questions and posting good answers to those concrete is the primary way to earn reputation. It's not a thread where you're joining in a discussion; either post a good well-researched question that you have about how to use an Apple product, or post a post a clear well-researched answer to someone else's question.

Answer (score 1):

Did our tour help at all with onboarding and expectations for how reputation work?

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour

Also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/165931 covers this in terms of the larger stack exchange idiom of Q and A (which seeks to optimize for good answers to specific questions as opposed to hosting good discussions and comments).  This distinction in goals is baked into the software of the site and it’s also something that does take some time to get used to if you’re familiar with forum software and not Q/A or knowledge base type software.

[Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) is an excellent example of a place to discuss topics on par with Stack Exchange in terms of being open to everyone, but different in the primary goal it hopes to facilitate.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/reputation

Lastly, reputation and moderation are a system that tries to be in balance. Several of the people that commented are elected moderators. We volunteer here to help with situations where the regular distributed moderation process needs a little help (usually to speed up certain expected results). We also may have seen questions that you and all other new members of the community have when something like this post isn’t written yet or already obvious / searchable.